# Endomorphisms of products of elliptic curves

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose that we have a product $E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n$ of elliptic curves $E_i$ and that we know the endomorphisms $\text{End} E_i$  for each elliptic curve. Is it possible to use this to determine or at least find something interesting about $\text{End} (E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n)$ in any special cases (e.g. for elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$ or number fields)?

The first thing that I thought of was to use the Poincare reducibility/irreducibility theorem 
(see [Subvariety of Product of Elliptic Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174442/subvariety-of-product-of-elliptic-curves)) since it can be used to decompose $\text{End} A$ for an abelian variety $A$ into a product of endomorphisms of powers of simple abelian varieties. However, I'm not sure about how far this goes since it seems like finding concrete applications for this theorem seems pretty hard in general. So, it would be interesting to see other ways to approach this question.

Comment: The only other information you would need is morphisms from $E_i\to E_j$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide some more details? For example, what would happen if all the $E_i$ were isomorphic or isogenous to each other? Also, is it possible to get some kind of explicit answer (possibly with some extra conditions)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment, so I will explain here. Giving a morphism $E_1\times \cdots \times E_n$ to itself is just giving morphisms $E_1\times\cdots\times E_n\to E_i$ for all $i$. So, let us describe maps from the product to say $E_1$. Given such a morphism $\phi$, we consider the map $\psi$ defined as $\psi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-\phi(e, x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Notice that the second map $\phi(e,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$ is really a map from $E_2\times 
 \cdots\times E_n$ and so by induction, we have control over it. But, $\psi(e\times E_2\times\cdots\times E_n)=e$ and thus by rigidity lemma (if you do not know this, it is a very useful result and must look it up in say Mumford's Abelian varieties) one sees that $\psi$ factors through the projection $E_1\times\cdots \times E_n\to E_1$ and so essentially is just map from $E_1\to E_1$.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Comment: One question: Do you mean that any maps of $E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n \rightarrow E_i$ or ones with a suitable restriction? I think this would give $\prod \text{Hom}(E_i, E_j)$ for the endomorphism ring. If there aren't any restrictions I'm not sure if it would give a well-defined endomorphism of $E_1 \times \cdots \times E_n$.

Comment: I do not understand your question. A morphism from say $X\to Z\times T$ is completely determined by two morphisms $X\to Z, X\to T$, with no other restrictions.

Comment: I think I have understood your question. You are asking why $f:E_1\times E_2\to E_3$ is determined by knowing $E_1\to E_3, E_2\to E_3$? This of course is not true for arbitrary varieties, but true for elliptic curves. First, by translating on $E_3$, we may assume $f(e,e)=e$. Then rigidity says $f$ is a group homomorphism. Thus, $f(x,y)=f((x,e)+(e,y))=f(x,e)+f(e,y)$. I hope the rest is clear.

Comment: Thanks! This clarified everything.